# Isomorphism which involves $\mathbb Z_p[[T]] \otimes \mathbb Q_p$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

> Why should $\mathbb Z_p[[T]] \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Q_p$ be isomorphic to the bounded sequences with values in $\mathbb Q_p$?

The fact is that the tensor product is on $\mathbb Z_p$, so it is not true that  $\mathbb Z_p[[T]] \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Q_p$ is $\mathbb Q_p[[T]]$. Also *a priori* I can't see that the sequence is bounded.

Comment: The reason is the same as the reason to why $\Bbb{Z}[[T]]\otimes \Bbb{Q}$ is the subset of $\Bbb{Q}[[T]]$ with the sequence of coefficients having bounded denominators. Namely, the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p[[T]]\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}\Bbb{Q}_p$ are sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^m q_i r_i(T)$ with $q_i\in\Bbb{Q}_p$, $r_i(T)\in\Bbb{Z}_p[[T]]$, $m$ some natural number.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133777

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map
$$\mathbb Z_p[[T]]\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p}\mathbb Q_p\to\{\text{bounded sequences in }\mathbb Q_p\}\\\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iT^i\otimes z\mapsto(a_0z,a_1z,\ldots).$$

It is clear that the map is well defined, and takes an element of the domain to a bounded sequence, since $z\in\mathbb Q_p$ has a bounded denominator.

Moreover it has inverse given by
$$(x_0,x_1,\ldots)\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^\infty p^kx_iT^i\otimes p^{-k}$$
where $p^k$ is the supremum of the absolute values of the $x_i$.

Hence it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry for such a late comment!  Besides $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]] \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$, I have frequently encountered the Iwasawa algebra as $$\Lambda^{\mathrm{ur}} := \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} \mathbb{Z}_p^{\mathrm{ur}},$$ where $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\mathrm{ur}}$ is the completion of the integer ring of the maximal unramified extension $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{ur}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then do we have an intuition on $\Lambda^{\mathrm{ur}}$, similar to your answer here? (Or more precisely the image of it in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\mathrm{ur}}[[T]]$?) Sorry for such a comment.