# Polynomial analogue of $p$-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Consider a monic irreducible polynomial $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$ (equivalently, by Gauss lemma, it is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$).
What do the rings 
$$
R = \varprojlim_n \Bbb Z[X] / (P^n)  \qquad\text{and}\qquad 
S = \varprojlim_n \Bbb Q[X] / (P^n)
$$
look like? How are they related to the $p$-adic numbers (for some prime $p$)? How do they relate to $\Bbb Z[[X]]$ ? I first saw this construction [here](http://vixra.org/pdf/1708.0108v4.pdf) (hem!).

If $P=X$, then we have $R = \Bbb Z[[X]], S = \Bbb Q[[X]]$ (in particular, it is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133777) that $S = R \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Q$), and $R/(X-p) \cong \Bbb Z_p$ for every prime $p$. But what do we get if for instance $P = X^2 + 1$ ? Do we get someting like $R = \Bbb Z[i][[X]]$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to look close to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Generalizations_and_related_concepts) (but not exactly); in the chapter 4 of [this book](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~hecohen/numthrybook.pdf) it is even exposed as a starting construction (bypassing the ordinary $p$-adic one).

Comment: It is analogue of $p-$adic expansion. This is more or less formal taylor series around the solution of $P$.(Pick whatever your solution and this is a ring allowing you to do taylor series at that solution.) $Z[|x|]$ is a special case of this.

Comment: If we consider $\Bbb F_q[X]$ instead of $\Bbb Z[X]$, then I think that we get some local field of characteristic $p>0$.